# Completely and explicitly describe, up to isomorphism, the set of all complex irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Can someone please verify my answer to this question?

> Completely and explicitly describe, up to isomorphism, the set of all complex irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

For each $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, let $\phi_x$ be the homomorphism defined by $\phi_x(g) = \exp \left(\frac{2 \pi i gx}{n} \right)$. Then, each such homomorphism describes a complex irreducible representation of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of dimension one.

Comment: Have you seen the fact that irreducible representations of abelian groups are necessarily one dimensional?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yes, but my question is whether the representations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct, and you can check a derivation of this result in J.P. Serre's *Linear representations of finite groups*, in chapter 5, section 1.